# Add tableView to a custom View

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xib, custom-view

I'm sure this might be fairly easy but I'm unable to do it. I have a custom View xib [image: customView.xib]

and on basis of either segment selection I want to show one of my two tableViews. When tableView xib is loaded with

```
    _userProfileView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UserProfile" owner:_userProfileView

                                                        options:nil]firstObject];
```

tableViewDataSource and Delegate methods are called on CustomView not on UserProfileView.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: yes, they are called on View because you have placed table view inside of  CustomView.

Comment: if you want they are called on UserProfileView then create new Protocol in CustomView and set its delegate from UserProfileView.  check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c?lq=1 for creating delegates.

Comment: @darshan UserProfileView has button on it. So button action should be placed in customVew.m or UserProfileView.m ?

Comment: You should set button action in view where it is placed so it will be in UserProfileView.m

Comment: @darshan I'm pretty new to all of this so is it the right approach to place button action in UserProfileView and tableViewDatasource and Delegate methos in CustomView ? and could u please write it as answer to I can accept it ?